# Send array to function, multiply each variable by 2, return array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, function

i am tryin to make a function that takes an array and multiples each of its values by 2, then returns each multiplied value in a new array, so I can write out the individual values of the original array and the new multiplied one. 
IE, an array with 2, 4, and 6, I want to make a function that takes it, then multiplies each value by 2, then return a new array that has 4, 6, and 8.

Here is my function

```
public static int[] ArrayFunction(int[] array)
{
     int multiply = 0;
     foreach(int i in array)
     {
         multiply = i*2;
     }
    int[] multiArray = new int[] {multiply}
return multiArray;
}
```

I'm just trying to return an array with each value of the original array multiplied by 2.

Comment: Your return array will only have 1 value in it.

Comment: You need to stores the result of the multiplication into the new arrays at each iteration of the loop. In your example, you are setting the multiply variable but doing nothing with it

Comment: First declare the returning array with the same size of the input array. Then start the loop, but take the value at the loop index from the input array and multiply it by 2. Store the result in the same index but in the returning array. Probably someone here will write the code for you, but it is better if you try to do it by yourself. It is easy, just try it.

Comment: there is a free online C# tutorial you can read up on Arrays google `C# Basics Tutorial` also read all the examples here and understand them as well [C# Array Examples](https://www.dotnetperls.com/array)

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve the desired result by using the below code.

```
public static int[] ArrayFunction(int[] array)
{
     int multiply = 0;
     int count= 0;
      int[] multiArray = new int[array.Length];
     foreach(int i in array)
     {
         multiply = i*2;
         multiArray[count]=multiply;
         count++;
     }
     return multiArray;
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect by the way `int[] multiArray = new int[array.length];`  it should be `int[] multiArray = new int[array.Length];`
`length` and `Length` are not the same

Comment: use i for index? Isn't that the value in the input array?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

you can use `ToArray`.

> ToArray(IEnumerable) method forces immediate query
>   evaluation and returns an array that contains the query results. You
>   can append this method to your query in order to obtain a cached copy
>   of the query results.
>   for more see [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public static int[] ArrayFunction(int[] array)
{
    return array.Select(i=>i*2).ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use @tabby's method just remember to add "using System.Linq" this might seem obvious but its something I didn't know so for someone who needs the help.